# What does '$' really mean in '$scope' angular varialble

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this code does work

```
<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_ctrl">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("my_app", []);

    function ScopeController($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Another John";
    }
    app.controller("my_ctrl", ScopeController);
</script>
```

And this doesn't

```
function ScopeController(scope) {
    scope.firstName = "John";
    scope.lastName = "Another John";
}
```

As far as I understand programming, `$scope` is just a local variable for `ScopeController`. And `ScopeController` itself is just a callback function. So why correct work of my code depends on how I name callback's local variable? If it's not just a local variable, then why it passed as an argument?

Comment: It doesnt mean anything. It's up to you how you name your variables. You can always tell the injector to inject $scope service into your class and name it foo or $bar

Comment: your premise is flawed.  The second example code works fine

Comment: Hence his question I think : why does the variable name "$scope" work, but not "scope" ?

Comment: Because services are registered by name and there is no service called 'scope' in angular. Please check the documentation on how the dependency injection in angular looks like.

Comment: Blame on w2schools tutorials which say about controllers, but don't say about dependency injections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. `$scope` is simply the name of the scope service. Angular prefixes most of its stuff with a `$` in order to avoid stepping on names that *you* choose, so *you* won't have to prefix all your clashing names with `$` or something else. It ceases to work when you simply call it `scope`, since Angular figures out which services it should inject based on the name of the paramter; and it doesn't know any service called `scope`. To make the variable name arbitrary, use the annotated syntax to define your controller:

```
function ScopeController(scope) { ... }

app.controller('my_ctrl', ['$scope', ScopeController]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` is an Angular keyword. Angular will look for specific variable names like `$scope` or `$timeout` and inject the corresponding services and modules.

It doesn't work with `scope` because Angular's core has no such thing as a `scope` service.

For that matter, it's a problem with minification : Since code minifiers mangle variable names to save up bytes, they transform `function ScopeController($scope)` into `function a(b)`. And Angular is then lost. It doesn't know what `b` is.

In order to work around this, we use plain strings to inject the controllers :
`app.ScopeController([ "$scope", function($scope) { .... };] )`.
This gets then minified into `app.a([ "$scope", function(b) { .... };] )` but it's okay because strings don't get minified and Angular knows that `b` refers to `$scope`.

Comment: Really, is my question that bad?

Comment: What? What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, don't mind that. These are serial downvoters, they downvote everything without giving a reason. They are the pleague of StackOverflow. Your question looks good to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about injecting dependencies in Angular.
Yes, `ScopeController`ist a function, but it is passed into `app.controller()` where it is registered as a new controller within your app. The name of this new controller is "my_ctrl".
`$scope` is a Service, which will be injected into your `my_ctrl`on instantiation. You access the controllers Scope via `$scope`, after that, as you already do.

`$scope`tells angular -> use my internal `$scope service`, whereas `scope` might be something you wrote on your own.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer deceze provided, this is true of any service. It all depends on how you do dependency injection. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyService() {
    this.value = 'hi';
}
app.service('MyService', MyService);

function MyController(MyService) {
    var val = MyService.value; // 'hi'
}
app.controller('MyController', MyController);

function MySecondController(ms) {
    var val = ms.value; // 'hi'
}

// this is the key. if you use this method then you
// can call you parameter whatever you want in the controller
app.controller('MySecondController', ['MyService', MySecondController]);

// this will work similarly to the MySecondController
function MyThirdController(service) {
    var val = service.value; // 'hi'
}
MyThirdController.$inject(['MyService']);
app.controller('MyThirdController', MyThirdController);
```